# How to preload images in vue using @load?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a problem with preloading in vue. Problem is that i need to know when the last image has loaded and rendered in the DOM, in order to perform some other stuff. Never mind the data, the images renders etc. What i need to know is how to check for when the last one is loaded and rendered. Figured i could use the `imgLoaded` from data but that does not make any sense since it does not detect which one's the last. How can i do this?

Template:

```
  <section v-for="(slice, index) in slices" :key="index" :data-id="index" class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
    <div class="max-w-[70%]">
      <img v-if="index > 0" :src="slice.items[0].image.url" @load="preload">
    </div>
  </section>
```

Js

```
data() {
  return {
    imgloaded: false
  }
},

preload() {
  this.imgloaded = true;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the last image you can do this :

```
<section v-for="(slice, index) in slices" :key="index" :data-id="index" class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="max-w-[70%]">
    <img v-if="index > 0 && index === (slices.length - 1)" :src="slice.items[0].image.url" @load="preload">
    <img v-else-if="index > 0" :src="slice.items[0].image.url">
  </div>
</section>
```

But to know if the DOM has been rendered you can use mounted hook (https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted) :

```
mounted() {
  this.imgloaded = true;
},
```